# target="_new" not working in google map marker window

Tags: html, google-maps

I added marker to map , on click of marker i am displaying some text and hyper link with target="_new" , here is exact html

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" ,target="_new"> Get Directions</a>
```

but its opening url in same tab, instead of new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove comma before target attribute.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_new"> Get Directions</a>
```

Comment: hmm , i tried _blank too but same issue , and btw _new also do the same thing ,its better than _blank

Comment: Got it. it's because of the comma before target attribute. Remove it and it will work :)

Comment: yeah thats the issue!, its working fine now with _new :)  , thanks for help.